# Save Changes in activity onPause()

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

am having an activity which has a recycler view that displays data fetched from database , it displays products to add in cart so user sets the quantity of the product .

all good here..but

once activity goes to onPause() the quantity is deleted and all set back to zero.

how can i use shared preferences or saved instance to keep the quantity data glued to the textView..?

a sample code will be helpful

please help

Comment: https://www.ankitpalli.com/2017/06/simple-cart-system-in-android.html. There are plenty of tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its good idea to avoid losing data or state.

1. Save Instance state by Implementing onSaveInstanceState Method.

   ```
   @Override 
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("productName",productText.getText().toString());
    outState.putInt("quantity", Integer.parseInt(quantityText.getText().toString())); 
   }
   ```
2. Restore in onCreate.

   ```
   if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        productText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("productName"));
        quantityText.setText(String.valueOf(savedInstanceState.getInt("quantity")));

    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SharedPreferecnes, use the ViewModel class that specific purpose is to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle-conscious way. The ViewModel class allows data to survive configuration changes such as screen rotations.
[image]
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel