# Showing the number of quantity when press + button and decrease - button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I wanted to show the number of quantities and price where `price = (single item price * the total number of quantities)`. I understand how to show the items but I'm struggling with how to put buttons for each item and displaying their quantity. How to add `+` and `-` for each row and on click on the button calculate the price respectively. My concept is like a shopping cart but it shows the quantity and the `+` and `-` buttons and the price.

```
    public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    String data1[],data2[];
    int images [];
    Context context;

    public myAdapter(Context ct, String s1 [], String s2[], int img[] ){
        context = ct;
        data1 = s1;
        data2 = s2;
        images = img;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mytext1.setText(data1[position]);
        holder.mytext2.setText(data2[position]);
        holder.myimage.setImageResource(images[position]);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView mytext1, mytext2 , quantity;
        ImageView myimage , plus , minus;


        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mytext1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Nama_Pakej);
            mytext2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Harga);
            quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            myimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            plus    = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tambah);
            minus   = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tolak);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (itemView == plus){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my adapter. I'm using card view to display my items.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve "price = (single item price * the total number of quantities)"  use a simple method -

```
public double mul(double quantity, double price) {
    return quantity * price;
}
```

Then use increment and decrement and update the quantity and total price . example- here single item price 100 .

```
       private int increment;
       private int decrement;
       private String totalprice;

     plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //TODO
        //Increment
        increment = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString());
        increment++;
        quantity. setText(String. valueOf(increment));
        //update price
        totalprice = String.valueOf(mul(increment, 100));
        mytext2.setText(totalprice);
    }
});

     minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //TODO
        //Decrement
        decrement = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString());
        decrement--;
        quantity. setText(String. valueOf(decrement));
        //update price
        totalprice = String.valueOf(mul(decrement, 100));
        mytext2.setText(totalprice);
    }
});
```

You can check also my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66737085/4327305) to avoid losing data while activity lifecycle changes .

Comment: can i know shuld i put this inside the adapter...because i'm using a cardview so theres that holder thing that needs to be notice...because there's going to be 4 items with each of their own plus button. I have to use [position] to determine which plus button i'm referring to so can this be use?